# Call a function when window is resized inside a shopify theme

Tags: javascript, shopify

I'm trying to make some customization in a Shopify theme (the Brooklyn one). In this theme, there is a file `theme.js.liquid` in which they define a very large function `slate.Variants()`. Within this function, I defined another function `filterSlidesOnMobile(variant)` and call it within the large function `slate.Variants()`.

I want to call my function `filterSlidesOnMobile(variant)` every time the windows resize. I tried to use jquery functions like `resize()` and `onresize()` within and out of `slate.Variants()` but no sucess. The problem is my function has a parameter `variant` which is defined in `slate.Variants()`, so it's obvious that calling the resize out of it won't work, but even when calling the resize within it, there is syntax errors like when I do `$(window).resize(this.filterSlidesOnMobile(variant));`, I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Where should I call the resize and how?

I precise that I'm new to Js and that any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** As requested, here is a [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/ziFKN0Nf) to the function `slate.Variants()` in which I did all my work.
Look up for lines 27 - 114 - 127 and 156. (This is what I added: except those lines, the theme file didn't change).

Comment: please may you provide a [mcve]? as what has been shared so far isn't enough for us to answer

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of this custom product and why you want to run it over window resize?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm trying to find a way to do that. It's complicated because the theme is complex.

Comment: @OnkarSingh The purpose of the function I coded is to filter the product page slides (on mobile view) based on a variant change. I call it when a variant change and on a page load. I want to call it also on window resize because I noticed when I'm on desktop view and make my window so small that the slider appears, it doesn't call my function (and then the filter doesnt work)  and I need to reload the page to call my function and make it work.

Comment: to this, you edit the same functions and add code in which the images slider is created?

Comment: @OnkarSingh For doing that I created my function in Variants.prototype in slate.Variants(). Basically if you have the Brooklyn theme: I coded it after the function _updateMedia (variant) and then call it in _onSelectChange() to trigger it when a variant is changed and in Variants(options) to trigger it on page load. And my function does more or less a .slick('slickFilter') and .slick('slickUnfilter') to decide which slides to show or not.

Comment: okay, so it works well when someone changes the variation, now the issue is when someone reloads the page it doesn't work until the variant does not change, right?

Comment: @OnkarSingh Actually it works well for both a variant change and a page load. I want to also do it for a page resize.

Comment: okay, I am not 100% sure but you can use the `enquire.register(theme.variables.mediaQuerySmall, {
      match: function() {
       // if matched goes here
      },
      unmatch: function() {
        // not code here
      }
    });`

Comment: @evolutionxbox I edited my question to add a pastebin link. Doing a minimal reproducible example is too much complicated for such a Shopify theme. Sorry.

Comment: @OnkarSingh This idea seems worthy to try. But I can't because I don't know where to call it since my function need an argument (the variant) and that's all the problem about resizing.